# PANDOC: Custom docx template stopped working

Tags: docx, pandoc

I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.1. I've been using Pandoc 3.1.2 with a custom template for docx output, and it was working fine, but suddenly stopped working. The template I'm using is named 'custom-reference.docx' I'm now getting the error "File custom-reference not found in resource path"

My command line is:

```
pandoc test1.md -f markdown -t docx --metadata title="test1" -s -o test1.docx --reference-doc=custom-reference
```

I expected it to output a docx document using the template I specified. Instead I got the error "File custom-reference not found in resource path"

I checked where it should be looking by using --version, it returned `/Users/NAME/.local/share/pandoc`. The file custom-reference.docx is there. I can open and edit it in word and the text was created by pandoc. I recreated the custom-reference.docx from scratch to be sure.

using --data-dir= option doesn't seem to make a difference, I get the same error.

Again, this was working a week ago! Not sure where to go from here to troubleshoot. Help appreciated.

Comment: For me it works when adding the full filename (with extension), so `--reference-doc=custom-reference.docx`.

Comment: Thanks. I get the same error, except it appends the docx in the error, "File custom-reference.docx not found in resource path"